# PHP Packages Cloudinary and Semaphore Conflict

Tags: php, semaphore, cloudinary

Can someone help me with this? Is there a way to install Cloudinary With Semaphore When trying to install cloudinary after installing semaphore it shows this error. And also Vice Versa.

Btw Semaphore is a SMS API

> Problem 1
> Root composer.json requires cloudinary/cloudinary_php ^2.11 -> satisfiable by cloudinary/cloudinary_php[2.11.0].
> cloudinary/cloudinary_php 2.11.0 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle ^6.5.8|^7.4.5 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.5.8, 7.4.5, ..., 7.7.0] but the package is fixed to 6.0.2 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

I tried updating the guzzlehttp and also tried to install cloudinary first before semaphore and still gets the error.

Error when i try to update guzzlehttp

> Problem 1
> Root composer.json requires guzzlehttp/guzzle 7.4.5, found guzzlehttp/guzzle[7.4.5] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
> Problem 2
> kickstartph/semaphore-client is locked to version 0.5 and an update of this package was not requested.
> kickstartph/semaphore-client 0.5 requires guzzlehttp/guzzle 6.0.2 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.2] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (7.4.5).

Thank you if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to update the dependency for kickstartph/semaphore-client?

Otherwise, you should be able to roll back the guzzle dependency to 6.0.2 in your composer.